# How to write a custom command in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to implement a `hover` command in Cypress, so I'm doing this:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("hover", { prevSubject: "element" }, (subject) => {
    return subject.trigger("mouseenter");
});
```

And using it like this:

```
cy.get(`[test-id="my-test-id"]`).hover();
```

But it's not working: the `hover` call doesn't seem to have any effect on the execution of the test.

If I remove the custom command and just put the contents of that function inline, it works:

```
cy.get(`[test-id="my-test-id"]`).trigger("mouseenter");
```

What am I doing wrong with the custom command?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by *"not working"*?

Comment: Ah sorry, sure: With "not working" I mean that I don't see any effect of having  `cy.get(...).hover()` vs. just removing the line. It's as if the method call was not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping the subject first?

```
cy.wrap(subject).trigger("mouseenter");
```

Comment: Thanks! Wrapping the subject made the custom command work. Notice though that is not `mouseover` that worked, but `mouseenter`. Why is wrapping necessary in this case?

Comment: `mouseover` was my typo, sorry.

As to why: I'm new to a lot of this stuff, but my impression is that the object passed in is not chainable, or rather it will not provide a yield. `cy.wrap` causes it to provide a yield to functions further down the chain.